# GPIO state changing by it self

Tags: gpio, pi-3, relay

I designed a pcb which has two AC channels connected to relays which are eventually controlled by gpios for sure...

the first channel is working great

except for the second channel ... when I set its GPIO hight it works for about 0.5 to 1 second then it turns back off ...

The gpio it self goes of ... I am trying this by terminal not using python or anything..

```
sudo gpio -g mode 04 out
sudo gpio -g write 04 1
// Now gpio works for 1 second and then goes back to DOWN state
```

Any ideas why this is happening ??

Comment: How exactly are you driving the relays? Is there sufficient current to run both at the same time? Does it happen only when both are on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the command you issue is intended to set GPIO 4.

The most likely explanation is you have the 1-wire bus enabled.  By default the 1-wire bus is implemented on GPIO 4 and checks devices every few seconds.  That will change the GPIO back to being an INPUT.

Either disable the 1-wire bus by removing or commenting out the `dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4` entry from `/boot/config.txt` or change the GPIO it uses.